# Set python version in heroku review apps

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, heroku-review-app

The review apps are running on the latest python version 3.9.4 and that seems to break the installation of pandas. I'm currently using review apps to review PRs. I have set the runtime to use python version 3.8.6 but that only works for the app in production. Is there any way to set the python version for review apps?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems setting a [python runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) fixes it(make sure to update the branch before trying to check unlike me).